# "Building your first app" run time errors with Eclipse-ADT

Tags: eclipse-adt

I'm working on the "Building Your First App" under Android's app creation training.  I have completed all the steps, and am running the app through my Galaxy S4.  It loads the first page entirely where the user enters in whatever they like, and then takes you to the second page displaying what the user typed in.  Loading the second page is where things go wrong.

```
    02-07 16:21:06.167: W/dalvikvm(21946): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a4898)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendmessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3825)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendmessage [class android.view.View]
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
    02-07 16:21:06.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21946):    ... 11 more
```

I'm a little overwhelmed on where to even start alleviating this problem..

active_display_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

This is the onCreate() under the DisplayMessageActivity class:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    //set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: post the code, specifically the onClick event handler for the button and the main activity class -  The issue is: Could not find a method sendmessage(View)

Comment: Well, good news is going through and getting the code to copy paste into here, I saw that under the <button/> I had: sendmessage   .. having a lower case m instead of a capital M.  Now the app doesn't crash, which is fantastic, but not on the second screen it displays "Hello_World!" Instead of the user message.

Comment: I solved all the issues I had, with the assistance of Sorceri!

The first one being a grammatical error in the code.  The second you can see above in onCreate in the DisplayMessageActivity class. All I did was cut out:

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

And it started working properly! Can't answer my own question. >.>